# Serialize into JSON with some library then deserialize with another library

Tags: android, json, rest, web, service

I'm a newbie in android development so sorry if my question is somehow irrelevant. I'd like to connect my app to a java restful web service, created with jersey 2.0. And I'd like to know if it's possible to serialize my datas using the built-in converter of jersey, then deserialize them on my android app with jackson for example. if it's possible, is it a good solution to look at? Fact is I like Jackson, that also has a reputation of being very fast, and in the other side the built-in converter of Jersey (a simple jaxb converter if I'm not mistaken) seems pretty easy to use so well, I kind of like it too. I'm just looking for the best way of setting all this.

Comment: What best way ? Serialization and deserialization happen just like you described. The only variable is the library. Some use Jackson, some use Gson or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it doesn't matter what tools you use, JSON is JSON.  As long as jersey is creating something that's actually JSON, and not just JSON-like (which I assume it is) Jackson should handle it fine.